# How to convert Julian Date to UTC in c#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, utc, julian-date

I convert from UTC to Julian Date. But I need to convert Julian Date to UTC. I researched but I didn't find any code in c#

I did `UTC to Julian Date`
I need `Julian Date to UTC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this extension method:

```
public static class DoubleExtensions
{
    public static DateTime JulianDateToUtc(this double julianDate)
    {
        var sinceEpoch = julianDate - 2440587.500000D;

        return new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddDays(sinceEpoch);
    }
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
2458324.500000D.JulianDateToUtc();
```

Comment: thanks! 
P.S **Edit this to** `JulianDateToUtc(2458324.500000D);`

Comment: No problem. If you want to use it that way, get rid of the "this" keyword in the message signature. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: I am sorry for disturbing. I have a problem. So I convert UTC (any date) to Julian Date, when I try converting **Julian Date to UTC** I always get the same date `(25.07.2018)`. How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/2.2.x/userguide/calendars) library `FromJulianDayNumber` method to do the conversion to an instant from which you can get UTC, it will handle all of the minutia that the accepted answer does not handle.